# Checking Typescript generics against multiple constraints?

Tags: javascript, typescript

E.g. I have a function to accept an array of configs. Each array element can be a subset of the config. I'll merge every array element into a single config, which should match the `Config` type.

I'm currently doing it this way:

```
type Config = {
    a: number,
    b: number,
    c?: number,
};

function fn(arr: Partial<Config>[]) {}

fn([{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 }]); // ok
fn([{ a: 1 }, { b: 1 }]); // ok
fn([{ a: 1 }]); // invalid config, but no TS error
```

The last function call is missing the required `b` property. I want to check the whole array against the `Config` type. I figured out this hack that seems to work:

```
// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never;

function fn<T extends Partial<Config>>(
  arr: T[] & (UnionToIntersection<T> extends Config ? any : never),
) {}

fn([{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 }]); // ok
fn([{ a: 1 }, { b: 1 }]); // ok
fn([{ a: 1 }]); // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4AoKKAChiggA8c4ATfKAIZwQUAPwsA1gC5YASlpUAbkgQ8oMuBEV5Z7LhF79mzaVARwAZnigZ5SlT13iM6qJu24A3PXqhIUAGEUCwQAczooAG9GJkENAFcAWwAjPAAaGKZkhJT0zKgiURzU3AyAX296C3i4EjIoCwpUPW4+KAAFAVxSAQAbciDLMKoqZnyu3BlUAG0AXSgAMhZ4MnQsHAJiUhRyVBpOVv5BkPDxIRENLR0M3Uiyn0bmaci4qABGNKhs98+iGTeoGVZrJvI9nq8AWVPi9vpDgaC4E8XgJ-oD4fQgA)

Is there a non-hacky way to do this? Ideally, the error message would be clearer.

**Edit:**

As jcalz pointed out in the comments, my solution doesn't work for `fn([{ a: 1 }, { c: 3 }])`. This is because:

```
const arr = [{ a: 1 }, { c: 3 }];
type T = (typeof arr)[number];
/* type T = {
    a: number;
    c?: undefined;
} | {
    c: number;
    a?: undefined;
} */
type T2 = {
    a: number;
    c?: undefined;
} & {
    c: number;
    a?: undefined;
}; // never
```

I thought `(typeof arr)[number]` would be `{ a: number } | { b: number }`. This fixes it:

```
type OptionalKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: {} extends Pick<T, K> ? K : never }[keyof T];

type OmitOptional<T> = T extends any ? Omit<T, OptionalKeys<T>> : never;

function fn<T extends Partial<Config>>(
    arr: T[] & (UnionToIntersection<OmitOptional<T>> extends Config ? any : Config[]),
) {}

fn([{ a: 1 }, { c: 1 }]); // Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: number; }' but required in type 'Config'.
```

Comment: "The last function call is missing the required `c` property" do you mean `b`?

Comment: Yes, b! Fixed it

Comment: Your solution doesn't catch `fn([{ a: 1 }, { c: 3 }])` as far as I can tell; The type of `[{a: 1},{c:3}]` is `Array<{a: number, c?: undefined} | {a?: undefined, c: number}>` which when you intersect the elements gives `never`.

Comment: Is the input to `fn()` always an array literal of object literals, passed directly into `fn()`?  Do you just want to accept `fn(x)` where `x` is of type `Array<{a: number} | {b: number}>`?  What if any of the inputs ever themselves unions?  Like, if I call `fn([Math.random() < 0.5 ? { a: 1 } : { b: 2 }])`, what do you expect to happen?  I think there are probably a lot of caveats here no matter what one proposes.

Comment: It's not always literals, but for now, there aren't unions passed in. Ideally, it'll accept the input if and only if both `a` and `b` are in any of the array elements, duplicates are fine. In the case of `fn([Math.random() < 0.5 ? { a: 1 } : { b: 2 }])`, it should require both `a` and `b` in other array elements. However, it doesn't matter if it's not perfect, any improvements over my current type would be great

Comment: There's no way for the compiler to tell the difference between `const x = [Math.random()<0.5 ? {a: 1} : {b: 2}]; fn(x)` and `const x = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}]; fn(x)` at the type level, so to some extent what you want is impossible.  Do you consider [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLLPVm) an improvement or a "hack"?  (I'm not sure your version is a "hack" either.  You are trying to represent a type function very much like "the intersection of all the elements in the array should be `Config`", which is quite close to what you did.  But "hack" is in the eye of the beholder, so ‍♂️)

Comment: That's works great, thanks! I don't think union array elements are an issue, I can still have sanity checks in JS. If you make this an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: I will write up an answer but it might not be for a little while (it is close to my bedtime in my time zone).

Comment: Added an edit which fixes my solution, your addition of `Config[]` for clearer error message is really clever!

Comment: Is this an internal function or is it a public function that might be called from Javascript? Because typically API that takes options objects tend to be public API. The answer to this changes everything.

Comment: I'd probably try overloads and tuple types instead of arrays: `fn<T extends Config>([T]); fn<T,U>((T & U) extends Config ? [T, U] : never); fn<T, U, V>((T & U & V) extends Config ? [T, U, V] : never); …`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that callers of `fn()` pass in an array they already had lying around instead of always passing in an array literal, the compiler might not know the specific types of each element in the array.  That is, the passed-in array might not be of a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types):

For example:

```
const arr = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }];
/* const arr: ({
    a: number;
    b?: undefined;
} | {
    b: number;
    a?: undefined;
})[] */
```

Here, the compiler infers that `arr` is of type `Array<{a: number; b?: undefined} | {b: number; a?: undefined}>`.  And for all the compiler knows or cares, it could be an empty array, or an array of one value, or an array of a hundred values all of type, say, `{a: number; b?: undefined}`:

```
if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
  arr.pop(); // ‍♂️
}
```

So to some extent, what you want is not generally possible.  Or at least, you will have to decide whether to allow some arrays that turn out not to have all the properties in `Config`, or whether to disallow some arrays that turn out to have all the properties in `Config`.  False negatives and false positives are probably unavoidable.

---

That being said, I will suggest a "best effort" that has some chance of false negatives by assuming that a value of type `Array<X | Y | Z>` (an array whose element type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)) has at least one element each of type `X`, `Y`, and `Z`.  This is similar to assuming that the merged config will have the [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `X & Y & Z`, which is what you were doing with `UnionToIntersection`.

And a version of `UnionToIntersection` could be made to work once you account for the often-helpful-but-not-here [*normalization* of object literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#improved-type-inference-for-object-literals) that contribute to union types.  Since `[{a: 1}, {c: 2}]` produces types like `{a: number, c?: undefined} | {c: number, a?: undefined}`, a straightforward intersection will give `never`.  You could programmatically massage the element type into `{a: number} | {c: number}` and then intersect that to get `{a: number; c: number}`. But instead I'll do something a little different:

---

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never;

function fn<T extends Partial<Config>>(
  arr: T[] & (Pick<Config, AllKeys<T>> extends Config ? unknown : Config[]),
) { }
```

So `AllKeys<T>` will produce a union of all the keys present in any union member of `T`. While `keyof ({a: string} | {b: number})` is `never`, `AllKeys<{a: string} | {b: number})` is `"a" | "b"`.  If we assume that the array has at least one element of each union member type, and we assume that each key is definitely present in at least one element, then we can conclude that the merged config will have all the keys in `AllKeys<T>`.  And since `T extends Partial<Config>` is true, we can conclude that the merged config will be of type `Pick<Config, AllKeys<T>>` (using [the `Pick<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)).

The type `Pick<Config, AllKeys<T>>` should be quite similar to `UnionToIntersection<T>`, except that the latter is too sensitive to the particular property value types of `T`, while the former only really cares about keys, trusting that the values will be okay given that `T extends Partial<Config>`.

---

To make the error message "nice" (or at least "not terrible"), we are intersecting `T[]` (the inferred type of `arr`), with the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) `Pick<Config, AllKeys<T>> extends Config ? unknown : Config[]`.  If `T` has all the required keys of `Config`, then this will result in `T[] & unknown` which is `T[]` (intersections with [the `unknown` top type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) absorb the `unknown`).  If `T` is missing any required key, then this will result in `T[] & Config[]`, meaning that suddenly the compiler will expect that each element of `arr` should be a full `Config` instead of just a `Partial<Config>`.  This will mean that probably every array element will have an error associated with it, which is overkill, but at least the message has a chance of complaining that you are missing some keys instead of not being `never`.

Let's try it:

```
fn([{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 }]); // okay
fn([{ a: 1 }, { b: 1 }]); // okay
fn([{ a: 1 }]); //  error! Property 'b' is missing 
fn([{ a: 1 }, { c: 3 }]) // error! 'b' is missing
```

Looks good!  The compiler accepts the first two calls, and rightly complains about missing `b` in the latter two cases.

---

As pointed out earlier, though, there are false negatives in cases where the assumptions of having at least one element containing each key from the element type:

```
const emptyConfigs: Config[] = [];
fn(emptyConfigs); // no error, but problem at runtime
```

And if you throw away information the compiler needs to verify the keys of `arr`, then there can also be false positives:

```
const okay = [{ a: 1, b: 1 }];
const falsePositive: Array<{ a: number }> = okay;
fn(falsePositive);  // error, but fine at runtime
```

But hopefully these are acceptable to you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-sdzpZ1sn9pA+ioDroxDxVNk0AiaDqKDRUjsDiQG4gADkIDvsWj1Qq0BzsEVJM7j1dN+fL3uIHPbQvmNI5AoU4qK62imqW5j-vYCgvpupJwHmV4QGQFxKA63T9hwwi6O82BTk++wwRAcEIZ+1q1ko9Z4EAA)